# Access a JSON data from python in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, flask

I have a flask URL called register, where I collect the users's input and process them like so:

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def register_post():
    email = request.values.get("email")
    username = request.values.get("username")
    company_name = request.values.get("company_name")
    password = request.values.get("password")
    confirm_password = request.values.get("confirm_password")
    messages = register(email, username, password, confirm_password, company_name)
    success_message = (
        "Thank you for registering with us. We will get back to you shortly."
    )
    print("request values: ", request.values)
    print("messages: ", messages)
    if (len(messages) == 1) and (messages[0] == success_message):
        return jsonify({"code": 200, "message": messages[0]})
    else:
        return jsonify({"code": 400, "message": messages})
```

Based on the messages, I would like to display the messages with a native browser pop-up. I am trying to access that JSON data in Javascript like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/register",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (json) {
        alert(json);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
});
```

I get the JSON object in the browser but it doesn't alert anything in the browser. what could I be doing wrong?

Screenshot of the dev tools below:
[image]

Network tab
[image]

Comment: if I understand your question correctly this is a JavaScript question and not a python/flask question, could you remove the python tags?

Comment: both JS and Python

Comment: *"it doesn't alert anything in the browser"* - Then what does it do?  In your browser's debugging tools, are there any errors at all on the development console?  On the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  In the script debugger, is either the `success` or `error` callback function invoked?  What is the observed value of the parameter in that function?

Comment: "I get the JSON object in the browser" — What does that mean? Does it render in the main viewport? Are you looking at the response in the Network tab of the developer tools? Something else?

Comment: @JaromandaX can you throw more light pls?

Comment: @David It returns a JSON object, I just shared screenshots

Comment: @JA-pythonista - no - it's odd that you don't post any values for username, password etc, and python happily tries to run `register`

Comment: I passed the data from the form using action to that route, if that makes sense

Comment: `I passed the data from the form` no, you didn't pass any data at all in the `$.ajax` - however, the issue is that the form submit happened, so your $.ajax did not, that's why you get no alerts

Comment: @JaromandaX Oh, I think I get you, I should pass the data to the ajax? How can I get that data since I am returning a JSON object in that route?

Comment: @JA-pythonista: The screenshot shows you *navigating to* the `/register` route, not making an AJAX request.  As the answer below indicates, you appear to be posting a form to that route instead of (or perhaps in addition to) making an AJAX request.  The problem is entirely unrelated to the server-side code or even to the code making the AJAX request.  The problem is that you are *navigating the user* instead of just making an AJAX request.  *Most likely* you just need to prevent a form submission or a button action somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You have some code which is navigating to `/register` so the JavaScript making the Ajax request is irrelevant.

Presumably you are submitting a form with `action="/register"`.

If you want to perform the Ajax request instead then you need:

- An event handler
- To prevent the default behaviour of submitting a form

```js
$('form').on('submit', evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    //... gather your data for the request body
    $.ajax(...);
});
```

Note that your existing JS is missing the `data` property from the object you pass to `ajax`. You'll need to populate that with the data you are sending.

Comment: How can I use the python function that does the major work for me?

Comment: @JA-pythonista — I don't know what function you refer to or what it has to do with your question or this answer.

Comment: this --> messages = register(email, username, password, confirm_password, company_name)

Comment: @JA-pythonista — I have no idea how that function is supposed to work. Any problems you having using it are a different problem to the one you ask about here (i.e. navigating to the response instead of making an Ajax request) and should be a new question.

Comment: yes, I am using it, your approach needs me to grab that register form right?

Comment: I have no idea what "grab that register form" means. This answer makes assumptions about the HTML you have but didn't include in the question.  The `register` function appears to only run after the request has been received by the server (which is after the point at which the problem you are asking about occurs).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248174/discussion-between-ja-pythonista-and-quentin).

Comment: Let's not. It doesn't seem relevant to the problem you are asking about. If you have a question about a new problem, then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).